# How to get my current location in android maps?

Tags: android, location, maps, parse-server

Actually my problem is I am not getting current location latitude and longitude I tried so many ways.I know that this question already asked in SO I tried that answers also still I didn't get answer.Please help me.

I want to get my current location in Map and set it in the location variable

This is my code:

**- onCreate Method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_location);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);
    requestKorsaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestKorsa);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
    if(provider == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Location for you", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}
```

**- onMapReady method**

```
   @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        updateLocation(location);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please wait for some time because GPS takes some time to fetch location.below are some good tutorial for that.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm

Comment: Both tutorials have some problems and are best avoided (in my humble opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was happening because I was trying to run my application in the emulator but when I was running in my device, it works. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

**Blow is my code working well,try this..i you have problem let me know**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.service.carrier.CarrierMessagingService;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Googlemap_currentlocation extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    LatLng latLng;
    //   GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    Marker currLocationMarker;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    private GoogleMap mMap;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemap_addresss);



        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


        mMap = googleMap;


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
     /*   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/


        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
      //  Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        settingsrequest();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {


            Log.d("location****", "@@@@" + mLastLocation);
            //place marker at current position
            //mGoogleMap.clear();
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

       /* mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Googlemap_addresss.this, OtherActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnectionSuspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnectionFailed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());



        //place marker at current position
        //mGoogleMap.clear();



        if (currLocationMarker != null) {
            currLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position.......");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        currLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.e("latitude", "latitude--" + latitude);

        try {
            Log.e("latitude", "inside latitude--" + latitude);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);




            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");
                }
                Log.d("maxaddress", "++++" + strReturnedAddress.toString());


            }else {
                Log.d("not wordkmap","$$$$$");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //zoom to current position:
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(14).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

  /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));*/

        //If you only need one location, unregister the listener
        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
//vendorlanchur.png
        //splashscreen.png
    }


    public void settingsrequest()
    {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(Googlemap_addresss.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
// Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    //   startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                      //  settingsrequest();//keep asking if imp or do whatever
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check Your manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Still what problem you  facing explain me i will guide You

Answer (score 0):

I just success to add the current location by taking example from: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples (see part of my current location) and add one file from this example project to my app: "PermissionUtils.java"